# How do I use find to copy and remove extensions keeping the same subdirectory structure

Tags: linux, bash, find, xargs, cp

I'm trying to copy all the files from one directory to another, removing all file extensions at the same time.

```
From directory 0001:
 0001/a/1.jpg
 0001/b/2.txt

To directory 0002:
 0002/a/1
 0002/b/2
```

I've tried several find ... | xargs c...p with no luck.

Comment: what should be behaviour be if there are two files (e.g. 1.txt and 1.jpg) in the same directory that have the same name besides the extension?

Comment: all filenames are prepended by a unique id so there is no risk of naming collisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursive copies are really easy to to with `tar`. In your case:

```
tar -C 0001 -cf - --transform 's/\(.\+\)\.[^.]\+$/\1/' . |
tar -C 0002 -xf -
```

Comment: +1 - you should change the regex: universally removing any extension, not only jpg (OP ask that) - but otherwise, nice solution.

Comment: this new regex is nearly ok, but what will do this one for example with the filename ".profile"?

Comment: Good solution. Tested with 260000 files (4 hours).

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't `tar` with `--transform` this can works:

```
TRG=/target/some/where
SRC=/my/source/dir
cd "$SRC"
find . -type f -name \*.\* -printf "mkdir -p '$TRG/%h' && cp '%p' '$TRG/%p'\n" |\
   sed 's:/\.::;s:/./:/:' |\
   xargs -I% sh -c "%"
```

No spaces after the `\`, need simple end of line, or you can join it to one line like:

```
find . -type f -name \*.\* -printf "mkdir -p '$TRG/%h' && cp '%p' '$TRG/%p'\n" | sed 's:/\.::;s:/./:/:' | xargs -I% sh -c "%"
```

Explanation:

- the `find` will find all **plain files** what have extensions in you SRC (source) directory
- the find's `printf` will prepare the needed shell commands:

  - command for create the needed directory tree at the TRG (target dir)
  - command for copying
- the `sed` doing some cosmetic path cleaning, (like correcting /some/path/./other/dir)
- the `xargs` will take the whole line
- and execute the prepared commands with shell

But, it will be much better:

- simply make an *exact* copy in 1st step
- rename files in 2nd step

easier, cleaner and FASTER (don't need checking/creating the target subdirs)!

Comment: I'm interested in the 2-step approach as the directory contains around 1000000 files. so FASTER is king.

Comment: Milion files? so, in this case (IMO) the two piped tar is the best solution. If you haven't tar with --transform, download it and compile. It sure will be faster than starting milion cp commands.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some find + bash + install that will do the trick:

```
for src in `find 0001 -type f`  # for all files in 0001...
do
  dst=${src/#0001/0002}         # match and change beginning of string
  dst=${dst%.*}                 # strip extension
  install -D $src $dst          # copy to dst, creating directories as necessary
done
```

This will change the permission mode of all copied files to `rwxr-xr-x` by default, changeable with install's `--mode` option.

Comment: +1 for this, I was about to write such answer. Most elegant here and proper tool :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this ugly duckling:

```
find 0001 -type d | sed 's/^0001/0002/g' | xargs mkdir
find 0001 -type f | sed 's/^0001//g' | awk -F '.' '{printf "cp -p 0001%s 0002%s\n", $0, $1}' | sh
```

The first line creates the directory tree, and the second line copies the files.  Problems with this are:

1. There is only handling for directories and regular files (no
   symbolic links etc.)
2. If there are any periods (besides the
   extension) or special characters (spaces, etc.) in the filenames
   then the second command won't work.